# Scala declare multiple variables at the same row with the first character as upper-case

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I'm trying to declare variables through tuple-assignment, such as:

```
val (hi, bye) = ("hi", "bye")
```

And obviously this is fine. However when having the first character as upper-case, the compiler explodes and complains about these variables not being already defined.

```
val (Hi, Bye) = ("hi", "bye")
```

Why doesn't this work? I'm running Scala 2.11.

By the way this works (as expected):

```
val Hi = "hi"
val Bye = "bye"
```

Comment: If you really need to have your val start with an uppercase, you can escape it with a back quote in pattern matching : `val (\`Hi, \`Bye) = ("hi", "bye")`

Comment: Oh that's nice, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Capital-letters-cause-tuple-unpacking-assignation-to-fail-td1942041.html):

> The tuple on the left-hand side is a pattern; names starting with 
>   capital letters are treated as constants when occurring inside a 
>   pattern. These constants must exist as values in the context. You find 
>   the exact semantics in the Scala spec under pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks! That explained it.